# Can I specify an entity's value as a specific form instead of a specific value?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an entity that the value can vary for each user (ex. "Turn on the lights at **room XYZ** where "room XYZ" is the value of an entity). Can I specify at the platform that the entity will be of the form `room $something` and how can I do this?

The response is not a problem since it will be handled by a backend. The problem is how do I send to the backend the whole value "room XYZ" instead of just "room"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at entity types for those parameters. Within that, you have a couple of options:

1. At the simplest, you could define this as type `@sys.any`. That would just pass the value to the backend and let it handle errors. (It does handle bad input gracefully, right?)
2. However, you can have entity types that you set at the beginning of the session using Dialogflow's [API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/). So once you know who the user is, you can get their list of devices, and set each device as a possible value for a user entity type. You'll need to create the entity type ahead of time (it doesn't matter with what) and then use the [/userEntities](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/userentities) endpoint if you're using the V1 API or the [project.agent.sessions.entityTypes](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.sessions.entityTypes) resource if you're using the V2 API to set the specific entities for that session.

(Choice 1 is easier, choice 2 will give you a better UX.)

Comment: Thank you so much! The first choice works like a charm I still have an issue with the second; indeed it recognizes that this is an entity but how do I get the value? I have an entity called `room` and one value in it `user_room`. If the user says turn on living room it recognizes that the living room is an entity but if I have the response as "**Turning on the $room**", it says "_Turning on the user_room_" instead of "_Turning on the living room_"

Comment: I found it :) The response should be "Turning on the $room.original". Thanks again!